# WPF store user object in cache or application properties

Tags: wpf

Mainly an asp.net guy, but was tasked with an application written in wpf. So far the adjustment hasn't been too bad. Just a quick question. Would it be better to store a user object (after successful login) in an ObjectCache or as an application property?

Comment: You just need to store the single current logged in user?

Comment: Yup! Just an object that contains some user settings, etc...

Comment: ObjectCache is for a collection.  If you just have the single current logged in user that I would go property.

Comment: If you need to store some information while the user is logged and the application is running you can use a simple instance of an object in memory.